# cross-domain ajax request get 412

Tags: ajax, http, tomcat, cross-domain

I have to do across-request from iPad to access tomcat webapp, sometimes this works, but if you send request repeat, the tomcat will return a `412` code. help!
The ios's codes is

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:[this is not a link]("http://192.168.1.222:8080/cmcp/doLogin"),
    timeout:600000,
    data: JSON.stringify({userName:"admin",password:"admin"}),
    dataType:"json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(nowData,textStatus,XMLHttpRequest )
    {

    },
    error :function(msg) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use dataType `JSONP` instead of `JSON`. `JSONP` is a viable solution for cross-domain **Ajax**

```
dataType: 'JSONP'
```

Please have a look at [Exaples](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/) and [Cross-domain Ajax -- brief introduction](http://json-p.org/).

Comment: It will help you, if its the corss-domain issue.